# Downloading a commercial font from a free source. Would that make an issue?

Tags: fonts, font-licensing, ethics

If a company is using a font-family as a part of their branding then how would someone know if the company has a license for it's use or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a commercial font license for small clients and derivative works?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46515/do-i-need-a-commercial-font-license-for-small-clients-and-derivative-works)

Comment: "someone gave it to me"

Comment: "Is it illegal to download music I haven't paid for from a free source?" "Is it illegal to download movies I haven't paid for from a free source?" "Is it illegal to download games I haven't paid for from a free source?" "Is it illegal to download artwork I haven't paid for from a free source?"

Comment: Can you please [edit] additional information into the question. Also please specify what you want to do with the font and why you wish to know. Please note that we do not like to assist in illegal activities.

Comment: Relevant reading: https://www.wired.com/2015/10/you-wouldnt-think-it-but-typeface-piracy-is-a-big-problem/

Answer (score 5):

If the font is being redistributed illegally, you're still liable for using it without a valid licence. The probability of getting caught depends on how you use it, but it is still illegal.

Comment: If an illegal font was used in a forest and nobody was around to see it was any law broken?  A good question for philosophy.se